# Will there be any voltage drop when connecting load to batteries?

Tags: batteries

In my project I am planning on using 10 AAA Batteries(to give me 12v as each battery is 1.2v) to power my project. I am wondering if there will be any voltage drop when I connect a load. If so how can it be calculated? This is so that I can account for it.

Comment: Also please note that there is no guarantee that you'll actually get 12V form batteries. I've seen 1.2 V batteries which give out as much as 1.6 V if the load isn't large enough.

Comment: The load should be large enough as i'm driving 2 stepper motors and then using a voltage regulator(7805) to power my circuit(which consists of a microcontroller, 3 sharp distance sensors and a ULN2803a).

Comment: please do not write a signature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the voltage will drop.  A reasonable approximation would be the internal resistance of the cells and other resistances in the wires, switches, etc, times the current consumption.

On an unrelated note, using 10 AAA cells sounds like a bad idea; AAAs have very poor energy density (wasted space due to the casing, etc) compared to AAs.  I would suggest using larger cells and a step-up regulator.  On a related note, larger cells also have lower internal resistances.

#### Energizer Datasheets/Whitepapers:

- [Battery Internal Resistance](http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/BatteryIR.pdf) technical bulletin
- [E92 cell](http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/E92.pdf) datasheet (AAA)

Comment: Its only got to power my device for less than 10 minutes then can be recharged. It also has to be as light as possible. Thats why i am using AAAs not AAs.

Comment: A step-up regulator is not going to be 100% efficient so the question is how do the losses associated with a step-up regulator compare with the difference of energy density between AA and AAA cells?  A regulator also adds cost but using 4 AA cells with a regulator compared to 10 AAA cells without would save money in the long run.

Comment: How much current does your device actually require at 12 V?  If it's less than 300 mA or so, you could get away with 2 AA cells, or possibly 4xAAAs as their internal resistance is about double.

Comment: It wouldn't produce enough current this is from just looking at a few quickly.

Comment: @Dean: How much current does your device require at 12 V/5 V?

Comment: If I remember correctly each coil requires 32mA theres 8 of them then unsure on the circuit yet to test it.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is it depends how much current your load draws.

The longer answer is, I believe, that if you are attempting to draw more current than the batteries can source chemically (batteries are not an "ideal voltage source"), you will see a the battery voltage dip sharply attempting to compensate for this imbalance. Regardless of this effect, the internal resistance of the battery will induce a voltage drop proportional to the current drawn by the load as well.

You can calculate the internal resistance of a battery (Rb) by (1) measuring the open circuit voltage (V) of the battery using a voltmeter, then (2) using a known resistor (R) (e.g. 5% 10kOhm resistor) and measuring the current (I) it draws from the battery (using an ammeter to complete the circuit). The deviation from V = I * R is due to the internal battery resistance, i.e. in reality V = I * (R + Rb) so... Rb = V/I - R.

Obviously the quality of that calculation is tied pretty much directly to the accuracy of the known resistor as well as the accuracy of your measurement equipment.

Answer (score 3):

There are two types of battery resistance:

Electrical resistance which is virtually instantaneous and usually constant.

Ionic resistance which is what causes the terminal voltage of the battery to rise after the load is disconnected and the battery has been left alone for a while; and vice versa, causing the voltage to decay after a few hundred milliseconds when a load is added.

If you're driving a stepper motor, both will be important. The first is important for any load really; but pulse loads such as stepper motors will be affected by ionic resistance more. If you step your motor on a battery with high ionic resistance you will find it runs fast for a few seconds but then slows down. The effect is more prominent on batteries near their end of life.

Answer (score 1):

If minimum weight is the aim then a converter with fewer. larger batteries will likely end up lighter overall, as you have fewer battery casings. Don't know offhand the weight difference between AA and AAA but capacity is about double.