# AC Adapter gives much more voltage than it's supposed to

Tags: voltage, adapter, ac-dc

**Hello!**
I have this one older AC-DC adapter from *Korg* (wallwart?)...

[image: Korg AC-DC 9V Adapter]

...that I have been using for my (guitar) effect pedals for a few years, and I recently found out (when I was doing some electronics doodling) that the adapter gives **much more** voltage than it's supposed to.
 I should give out +9V (as it is clearly seen from the picture), but when I measured the voltage by my multimeter, it is showing...

[image: AC-DC Adapted voltage measurement]

***...more than 14V!*** It freaked me out a little bit, since I may have been using it like this as a +9V adapted for my (expensive) delay, and that certainly could have been good for the pedal.

Does anyone have an idea of what's wrong with the adapter, since I have never opened it up or messed with it? Or am I measuring it wrong? And possibly, is there an easy fix?

*Thank you!*

EDIT: How can I find out that the adapter is "unregulated" (is it the same as unstabilized?) and it's not broken?

Comment: My 12V dc Yamaha wall wart outputs about 19V DC when unloaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Obviously, you have an *unregulated* power supply. If it's rated for 9V@600mA, and producing 14V2@Open.
2. To test for its output while driving your pedal, take the cover off your pedal (usually a trivial matter of removing a few screws); plug in the wall wart, then connect your meter leads to the pins of the peda's power jack. This will show you the highest voltage it's pushing into your pedal & let you get a better idea of how much to worry.

   - Remember, for most electronic equipment, overcurrent is more damaging than overvoltage. The only time that overvoltage without overcurrent is likely to damage equipment is when it exceeds the breakdown voltage of a component; most manufacturers will likely eaither include their own Vreg in an expensive piecd of equipment, or spec all their components to have a much higher breakdown voltage than the 'nominal' input voltage.

Answer (score 4):

Two options:

1. Well.. it might have gone bad but I doubt that.
2. More reasonable explanation is it gives off a bigger voltage than it is supposed to because it is unloaded. By that I mean that there is nothing connected to the power supply:

Let's take cars as an example. If you would measure a cars battery when the car is not running and when it is running (more so when you are starting it) I guarantee you that it would show a lower voltage when you are running it.

It is called voltage drop.    (or vdrop)
[Will there be any voltage drop when connecting load to batteries?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7346/will-there-be-any-voltage-drop-when-connecting-load-to-batteries)

[image]

Regulated supplies, without any load, should measure very close to the target voltage of 9v. Unregulated supplies will generally have a no-load voltage anywhere from a couple of volts to several volts higher.  So your supply is unregulated and that is the reason why it shows a way bigger voltage than 9v.

To simplify, I would not worry about it too much - the power supply is probably running well and working well.